# My use of Java generics with Collections.sort and Map won't compile

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm processing user data, grouping users by some external phrase and ordering on (external phrase, user name). I'm doing this in Java and am trying to make the phrase object and user object generic.  My target is Java 6.

Although everything is generic, in this example the external phrase is a String and the user is of type JUser.  My code refuses to compile, having issues with Collections.sort() and Map.put().

JUser:

```
import java.util.*;
public class JUser implements Comparable<JUser> {
    private String name = "";

    public JUser(String name) { 
        setName(name); 
    }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public int compareTo(JUser other) { return this.getName().compareTo(other.getName()); }
}
```

JLabeled:

```
public class JLabeled<K, V> {
    private K label = null;
    private V value = null;

    public JLabeled(K label, V value) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K getLabel() { return this.label; }
    public V getValue() { return this.value; }
}
```

JCollated:

```
import java.util.*;

public class JCollated<K, V> {
    private Map<K, List<V>> keyedList = new HashMap<K, List<V>>();

    public <V> List<JLabeled<K, V>> getAll() {
        List<JLabeled<K, V>> labeled = new ArrayList<JLabeled<K, V>>();
        List<K> keys = new ArrayList<K>(keyedList.keySet());
        java.util.Collections.sort(keys);
        for(K key : keys) {
            List<V> values = keyedList.get(key);
            java.util.Collections.sort(values);
            for(V value : values) labeled.add(new JLabeled<K, V>(key, value));
        }
        return labeled;
    }

    public <K, V> void createKey(K key) {
        if(keyedList.get(key) == null) keyedList.put(key, new ArrayList<V>());
    }
}
```

JTest:

```
import java.util.*;
public class JTest {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println("hello from JTest\n\n");
        testStuff();
        System.out.println("\n\ngoodbye from JTest\n");
    }

    public static void testStuff() {
        JCollated<String, List<JUser>> myCollated = new JCollated<String, List<JUser>>();
        List<JLabeled<String, JUser>> labeledList = myCollated.getAll();

        for(JLabeled<String, JUser> labeled : labeledList) {
            JUser user = labeled.getValue();
            System.out.println("Key: " + labeled.getLabel() + ", name: " + user.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling  **javac JTest.java**  the compiler says:

```
.\JCollated.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method sort(java.util.List<K>)
location: class java.util.Collections
        java.util.Collections.sort(keys);
                             ^
.\JCollated.java:11: incompatible types
found   : java.util.List<V>
required: java.util.List<V>
            List<V> values = keyedList.get(key);
                                          ^
.\JCollated.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method sort(java.util.List<V>)
location: class java.util.Collections
            java.util.Collections.sort(values);
                                 ^
.\JCollated.java:19: put(K,java.util.List<V>) in java.util.Map<K,java.util.List<V>> cannot be applied to (K,java.util.ArrayList<V>)
        if(keyedList.get(key) == null) keyedList.put(key, new ArrayList<V>());
                                                ^
4 errors
```

I am grimly amused by the statement that List and List are not compatible.  Can someone tell me what is really wanted here?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Comment: why the `java.util.` prefix? You already imported everything from there, using just `Collections` should work fine.

Comment: If you're in a generic class, you don't need to define a generic type on the method. The generic type `V` of the method `getAll` is not the same as the generic type `V` of the class `JCollated`.

Comment: Since I'm pretty lazy, just one: `java.util.Collections.sort(keys)` ..  the documentation clearly shows, that `sort` requires a generic list where the generic type extends `Comparable<? super T>` ... and what does your type `K` extend? Exactly: nothing.

Comment: I used java.util.Collections because I'm being lazy and still doing cut and paste in this program section.  Thank you Tom for finding the "extends nothing" bit, too.  Resueman, I will study more about why this V isn't the same as the class V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. If you want to be able to sort a `List` using [`Collections.sort(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-), the elements of the collection must be `Comparable`
2. Don't set any bounded type parameter in your method's definition otherwise it won't be understood by the compiler as the same types as those defined in your class's definition even if you use `K` or `V` in both places.

The code should then be:

```
public class JCollated<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V extends Comparable<? super V>> {
    ...

    public List<JLabeled<K, V>> getAll() {
        ...
    }

    public void createKey(K key) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Response Update:**

In the method `testStuff()`, you don't define properly your object of type `JCollated`, it should rather be:

```
JCollated<String, JUser> myCollated = new JCollated<String, JUser>();
```

Comment: I'm wowed by the prompt and useful answer.  I independently caught that the testStuff() of JCollated<String, List<JUser>> was wrong. But I didn't realize that the class declarations of K and V were sufficient for the whole file. My User and the Java String are comparable but I thought that the Generics interface was some kind of genius.  It needs more help that I gave it.  I made the suggested changes one at a time, back and forth, to see how it affected the compiler errors.  Thank you a whole lot! Jerome.